# PJSIP compilation for iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, pjsip

I am trying to compile pjsip for iphone simulator and getting the error:

```
../include/pj/config_site_sample.h:322:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
../src/pj/activesock.c: In function ‘activesock_create_iphone_os_stream’:
../src/pj/activesock.c:146: error: ‘kCFStreamNetworkServiceType’ is unavailable (declared at /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Headers/CFSocketStream.h:256)
../src/pj/activesock.c:147: error: ‘kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP’ is unavailable (declared at /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Headers/CFSocketStream.h:259)
```

Please help.

Comment: bypassed this error... using the following configuration.
export DEVPATH=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
export CC=$DEVPATH/usr/bin/gcc
export CFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -miphoneos-version-min=3.0" LDFLAGS="-O2 -m32"
now getting below error and not able to compile all the libraries
../src/pjmedia-videodev/ios_dev.m:66: error: cannot find protocol declaration for ‘AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate’
../src/pjmedia-videodev/ios_dev.m:88: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘AVCaptureSession’

how to bypass video for simulator ?

Comment: for the benefit of others:
make sure you have correct sdk and arch settings. I used the ones below.

export CFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -miphoneos-version-min=4.0" LDFLAGS="-O2 -m32"
export IPHONESDK=iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk
export DEVPATH=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
export ARCH="-arch i686"

Also it is weird that build/rules.mak has invalid spaces instead of spaces (check last few lines). replace the spaces with tabs and do

$ rm pjlib/build/.pjlib*
$ rm pjnath/build/.pjnath*

Now finally i got it compiled.

Answer (score 2):

for the benefit of others: used the latest pjsip from trunk.
change the below line to i686 in configure_iphone

```
for archpath in `ls -d ${SDKPATH}/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin*`; do
```

to

```
for archpath in `ls -d ${SDKPATH}/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin*`; do
```

and create config_site.h (pjlib/include/pj) with below lines

```
#define PJ_CONFIG_IPHONE 1
#include <pj/config_site_sample.h>
```

make sure you have correct sdk and arch settings. I used the ones below.

```
export CFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -miphoneos-version-min=4.0" LDFLAGS="-O2 -m32" 
export IPHONESDK=iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk 
export DEVPATH=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer 
export ARCH="-arch i686"
```

Also it is weird that build/rules.mak has invalid spaces instead of tabs (check last few lines). replace the spaces with tabs and do

```
$ rm pjlib/build/.pjlib* 
$ rm pjnath/build/.pjnath*
```

Now finally i got it compiled.

Comment: followed all steps but still doesn't work.

checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking host system type... i686-apple-darwin10
checking target system type... i686-apple-darwin10
checking for i686-apple-darwin10-gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
checking whether the C compiler works... no
aconfigure: error: in `/Users/thongchai/Documents/Projects/hlung_github/gossip/pjsip/source':
aconfigure: error: C compiler cannot create executables